# SlideMenu not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have [Side Menu](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) this as SlideMenu. But I want it to start from my ShopHome screen. And in my app my root/initial VC is Login page. When I use the below code it goes directly to ShopHome. But instead I want my app to start from Login and then menu on ShopHome screen. I tried changing root to my LoginVC but then menu doesn't work when I'm on ShopHome page.

**AppDelegate**

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShopHomeVC") as! ShopHomeVC
    let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightMenuVC") as! RightMenuVC
    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Any solution to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. On my LoginButton action changed my root.

```
@IBAction func loginButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShopHomeVC") as! ShopHomeVC
let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightMenuVC") as! RightMenuVC
let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
}
```

Thanks to @kaminara4 (GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

I checked Slide Menu

Use this and delegate add

```
 let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController
 let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as! RightViewController
 let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
 let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:  nvc,leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)

 slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
 slideMenuController.delegate = mainViewController
 self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: But by this my app would start from the VC where `SlideMenu` is present right ? I don't want it in that way

Comment: After VC you can change root  and make as Slide menu

Comment: How ? And can't this thing be done without setting rootViewController in AppDelegate ?

Comment: Make Your root vc in app delegate and after appdeegate instance use change root view controller simple

Comment: But how to change after that ?

Comment: Like this `self.shoppingCartVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: shoppingCart)` ?

Comment: Make loginvc  root controller than login click make  instance let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate  and change root view controller

Comment: Can  you please post it in answer. I'm still not getting it. After setting login as my root and then going to ShopHome. I can see the menu bar but when I click on it nothing happens.